# How can I retrieve inheritance information about a Class in AST eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently trying to implement a Eclipse plugin to calculate some OO metrics for Java application, as DIT (Depth of Inheritance Tree). However, i'm not being able to retrieve informations about a Class inheritance tree (distance between the class until Object). Assuming that a class is a CompilationUnit, I'm trying to getting into the class through the TypeDeclaration to compare if the class, for example, Dog (extends Animal) is a instance of Object. If not, it is done a recursive call to the visit method passing the Animal class as parameter, until the class is Object.

**EDIT** I managed to recover the superclass using `typeDec.getSuperClassType()`, however I need to get the TypeDeclaration of this superclass to call the visit method recursively, passing this TypeDeclaration as parameter.

This is the idea of my code:

```
public class ClassVisitor extends ASTVisitor { 

 depthOfInheritanceTreeIndex = 1;

 public boolean visit(CompilationUnit unit) {
    for (Object type :unit.types()){

        TypeDeclaration typeDec = (TypeDeclaration) type;

        Type superClassType = typeDec.getSuperClassType();

        TypeDeclaration superClazz;
        if (superClassType.equals(Object.class.getSimpleName())){
            return continue;
        }else{
            depthOfInheritanceTreeIndex++;
            superClazz = (TypeDeclaration) superClassType.getParent();
            return super.visit(superClazz);
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

Do you guys has any ideas in what i'm doing wrong or how to do that? Any help will be apprecieated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet here is to avoid using the AST API and use the Java model API instead.  The AST is meant to manipulate and analyze Java source code, but the model API is meant to analyze and manipulate the structure of a Java program.

The API is rooted in the `IJavaElement` interface.  You will need to do something like this:

```
IFile myJavaFile = <get the file>
ICompilationUnit unit = JavaCore.createFromFile(myJavaFile);
IType[] types = unit.getAllTypes();
for (IType type : types) {
  ITypeHierarchy th= type.newTypeHierarchy(null);
  // do something with the hierarchy
}
```

This will give you way more flexibility than generating the hierarchy based on the AST.  A few warnings, though:

1. This can take a long time to compute (especially for large hierarchy)
2. For this reason, you may want to only use the super type hierarchy if possible, which is much faster to compute.

Answer (score 2):

you can use`typeDec.resolveBinding().getSuperclass()` to get the super class as `ITypeBinding`. From there you can move up the inheritance tree by recursively calling `getSuperClass()` until it returns either `null` or `unit.getAST().resolveWellKnownType("java.lang.Object")`.

Comment: This approach has the virtue of staying within the AST API. Mixing the AST API with the Java Model API is possible, of course, but they have differing assumptions and behaviors.

Comment: unit.getAST().resolveWellKnownType("java.lang.Object") returns null for me. Is that due to misconfiguration of the eclipse jdt? i am using it on standalone mode

Comment: Works well when using JDT Core as a headless API.  The Java Model approach relies on IFile, which is tightly coupled to the Eclipse ecosystem (IProject, IWorkspace, etc.)